# Javascript private methods and property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
function person(name,age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;

let birthday = function() {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.age;
 }

this.data = function() {
    return this.name + " "+this.age + ' birthday: ' + birthday();
 }
}    

const l = new person('JOhn', 24); console.log(l.data());// NaN `
```

Why the value of this.age is NaN and what I should do?

Comment: Hi, Roman Azimi!  Where is `age` coming from?

Comment: Apart from this being a duplicate, try to learn modern javascript instead of year long obsolete code

Comment: @HoldOffHunger age is a property of constructor that its value is assigned when we instantiated a new object from the constructor .

Comment: I can see that.  This is just a function, not a constructor.  The code that is calling this function is not defining `age`.  That is likely your problem.  The code that calls the function, not the function.

Comment: No it's not @HoldOffHunger. The problem is that they try to access the outer `this` in a function that has his own `this`, with no property age in there.

Comment: Ah, good point, too.  Roman Azimi: Try that, try removing all this.var references, and just use the params as they're passed, `return name + " " + `, etc...

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Just read the linked answer and search for other `this` posts on SO and the internet. Your last recommendation is also false. `name` is undefined